# Laravel inserting large amounts of CSV data - QueryException

Tags: mysql, laravel

I hope that I wrote title good.

So I'm trying to read data from CSV file and insert data in specific mysql database table.

Everything is working as expected, only after some time it throws out this error -> shown in picture.

My CSV file is about 25'000 lines big, and around 12'000 line I get this error. Same is with second function, it throws same error around 6'000 line, same file, different filtering settings.

I also got different file with different function with 1269 lines, and it's inserting all data in database without problems. So might it be that it takes to long time or something like that?

[image]

Comment: If it fails on the same line everytime: check of the data on that line isn't crooked (like, a newline that's not escaped, or a comma too few). Try to insert the CSV file in chunks of 5K each and see if the problem occurs - could also be a timeout thing.

The error you sent is not not enough information and thus not really helping I'm afraid.

Comment: @Roboroads Yes, it breaks everytime on same line, but problem is that I'm not owner of this csv file, my customers business partners update this file daily with lefover stocks, so I can't influence this file. This is the only error that I get, or is there some other place where I can see more detailed error?

Comment: You can only fix this by fixing the file (least effort), or knowing the contents of that line (and the one before and after i guess) so you can add some workaround to that file (lot of effort).

Ask the exporter of the file if they have export options. It would be nice if they could escape all weird lines by adding quotes.

Aty least one thing is certain: the CSV file is crooked and you can do little about that.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in error log

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai How can I find it?

Comment: Okay, I found out what is causing this problem, only question is it possible to fix it in programmable way? I found that a lot of items, have problem with image links - "https://images.tyroo.de/GISLAVED_ULTRA_SPEED2    .jpg" betweern image name and .jpg there is spaces. In some places it's even 11 eleven spaces, some places 6 places, etc..

Comment: As this function with reading csv data and updating stocks, etc. Is called automaticly every 3 hours. (Client wants). So this time I deleted all spaces manually in excel. But I can't do that every 3 hours.

Comment: You could remove whitespace for that column specificaly with someting like `$sanitizedCellContent = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $cellContent)`.

Comment: you can find log in following dir ```storage path/logs/laravel.log```

Comment: @naghal Thank you for suggestion, but I tried all these 3 examples and none of them remove empty spaces - $item_image_link = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $image_link);
        $item_image_link = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $image_link);
        $item_image_link = str_replace(" ", "", $image_link);

Comment: @MsCrelix It will be hard to assist any further without at least the code sample where you reformat the content and insert it in the dabatase. Have you tried to output the content of the `$item_image_link` variable and see if whitespace are correctly removed?